# do while loop for recv () in Winsock

Tags: c, loops, tcp, winsock

I'm testing the byte order by sending a single frame (160x120) from LabVIEW to this C-program through TCP. I managed to convert the bytes to uint32 pixel values, but the problem is that the loop repeats printing the received data in the console application. The point here is that, I will print the received 19200(160x120) uint32 values and stop the printing at that value so I can examine the pixel values of the frame. Is that possible ?. The code:
(I have tried to change the "len" to "160*120" in the for loop, but I got some weird values in the console).

```
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
WSADATA wsa;
SOCKET s , new_socket;
struct sockaddr_in server , client;
int c;
int iResult;
int receivedCount = 0;
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
typedef unsigned int uint8_t;
unsigned int i;
size_t len;
uint8_t* p;
uint8_t value;

p = (uint8_t*)((void*)recvbuf);

do
{
  iResult = recv( new_socket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
  len = iResult/sizeof(uint8_t);

  for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
    value = p[i];
    printf("%lu\n",value);  
    }
}
while( iResult > 0 );

closesocket(new_socket);
WSACleanup();
}
```

Comment: Maybe my C is rusty, but why the double cast `p = (uint8_t*)((void*)recvbuf);`?  It seems to me that you could skip the extra cast here...  Also, is it possible that your data is broken up into multiple packets due to the size?  `19200*sizeof(uint8_t)` seems like a lot of data to be expected to fit in a single packet

Comment: The data is received as a stream of bytes. What do you actually mean by skipping the extra cast ?.

Comment: I just mean that you might write `p = (uint8_t*)recvbuf;` directly.  I know that the data is received as a stream of bytes, but I'm wondering if perhaps the stream is really a set of streams rather than just one; i.e., you might check how many times you get `iResult>0` because I suspect it will be more than one for the given data set.

Comment: I placed a breakpoint on that line, and the program detects the breakpoint. When I press continue to run, it then detects it afterwards and printing new pixel values in the console. So you were right I think. The data might be broken in multiple packets.

Comment: So then to answer your question, it would be a good idea to put an `overallUintsRecieved` variable that is incremented just after `value=p[i];` and gives you an indicator when `overallUintsRecieved > 160*120`.  And now you know why using `for (i=0; i< 160*120; i++)...` gives you bad data: you are reading beyond the end of the currently-read data packet and into uninitialized data.

Comment: You are printing bytes, not uint32's.  Are you sending 32 bit values or 8 bit values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To coalesce my comments, here is how I would rewrite your code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  WSADATA wsa;
  SOCKET s, new_socket;
  struct sockaddr_in server, client;
  int c, iResult, receivedCount = 0;
  unsigned long totalReceived = 0, totalExpected=160*120;
  char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
  int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
  typedef unsigned int uint8_t;
  uint8_t i, value;
  size_t len;
  uint8_t* p;

  p = (uint8_t*)recvbuf;

  do {
    iResult = recv(new_socket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    len = iResult/sizeof(uint8_t);

    for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
      value = p[i];
      totalReceived++;
      printf("%lu\n", value);
      if (totalReceived >= totalExpected) {
        printf("Retrieved expected data\n");
      }
    }
  } while (iResult > 0);

  if (totalReceived < totalExpected) {
    printf("Received less than expected: %lu < %lu\n", totalReceived, totalExpected);
  }

  closesocket(new_socket);
  WSACleanup();
}
```

This covers "double casting" changes, and capturing a data received count across multiple `recv` calls.